# Pencil drawing on a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to draw with a "pencilish" look on a tkinter canvas. I can draw on the canvas like how a marker draws, here is an image.

[image]

I would also like to be able to draw like in a "Pencilish" style, here is a picture to what I mean(pic from paint 3d)

[image]

I think it would be possible with `numpy`, `PIL` or `Open CV2` but I have no idea on how to draw a pencil sketch. The only info I could get is how to convert the whole image to a pencil sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide a minimal reproducible example. The code is left as an exercise to you:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import random

RADIUS = 10
SEEDS = 10

def random_point(x,y):
    a = random_angle = 2*math.pi*random.random()
    r = random_radius= RADIUS*math.sqrt(random.random())
    random_x = r*math.cos(a)+x
    random_y = r*math.sin(a)+y
    return random_x,random_y

def paint(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    canvas = event.widget
    for i in range(SEEDS):
        random_x,random_y = random_point(x,y)
        canvas.create_line(random_x,random_y,random_x+1,random_y+1,fill='black')
    

root = tk.Tk()
cnvs = tk.Canvas(root)
cnvs.bind('<Motion>',paint)
cnvs.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Happy coding!

Comment: hi sorry for not keeping the code i forgot to keep the main thing, I could easily implement this in my code but can you tell me wath `SEEDS` does in the program.

Comment: @Dodu `SEEDS` is the amount of pixels that are coloured while paint ist executed